# django-admin startproject throws CommandError

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and just started this tutorial on youtube. I'm currently trying to start my first project but it keeps throwing this error.
I'm trying to run: `django-admin start project [name]` and I get this error:

> CommandError: C:\Heights\Documents\Coding\manage.py already exists

The folder is empty. I also tried `django-admin start project [name] .` because I read it might solve this, but I still get the error.

Screenshots:
[image: Running django-admin in empty folder]

[image: Running django-admin . in empty folder]

I guess this is just some simple solution but i can't see what it is (:

Comment: The error is complaining that `manage.py` already exist in the folder (`manage.py` is created by `django-admin startproject`), and **both** your screenshots show that `manage.py` really is in the folder.  The *"empty folder"* in the names of your screenshots is not true.

Comment: @grochmal the screen shot was takes after running the command... It creates manage.py and then shows the comment. It also suppose to create some folders and python file but it fails and throws the error.

Comment: I'm more worried about `C:\\Heights\Documents\Coding\manage.py` (i can see that in the background) than about `C:\\Heights\Documents\Coding\new_project\manage.py`.  You need a clean directory tree.

Comment: What do you mean by a clean directory tree? Open it directly in C?!